# In Python, class from which a given instance is inheriting a particular method

Tags: python, inheritance, introspection

I know that in Python, given a class `ClassA`, with

```
inspect.getmembers(ClassA, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
```

I can iterate over the different methods present in `ClassA`. Inherited methods are also gathered, which is convenient in my case. But what I would need is, given a particular method `method1` of `ClassA`, to get the class from which `ClassA` inherited `method1`. It might be `ClassA` itself, or any of its parents/grandparents. I thought I could recursively traverse the `__bases__` attribute, looking for the `method1` attribute at each step. But maybe this functionality is already implemented somewhere. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look through the MRO (Method Resolution Order), using [`inspect.getmro()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) (which works on both old and new-style classes):

```
def class_for_method(cls, method):
    return next((c for c in inspect.getmro(cls) 
                 if method.__func__ in vars(c).values()), None)
```

There is currently no stdlib method to do this search for you, no.

Demo:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def class_for_method(cls, method):
...     return next((c for c in inspect.getmro(cls) 
...                  if method.__func__ in vars(c).values()), None)
... 
>>> class Base1(object):
...     def foo(self): pass
... 
>>> class Base2(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class ClassA(Base1, Base2):
...     pass
... 
>>> class_for_method(ClassA, ClassA.foo)
<class '__main__.Base1'>
```

If no base class is found, the above expression returns `None`:

```
>>> class Bar:
...     def spam(): pass
... 
>>> class_for_method(ClassA, Bar.spam) is None
True
```

Comment: I tested it and it exactly what I needed. Did not know about  `getmro`. Thanks!

Comment: @zeycus: I've refined it a little to be more robust in the face of overridden methods; it'll only find the *exact* base class a method came from, even if you passed in a method that has been overridden by a later baseclass now.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll use the improved version. These subtleties are way beyond my current OOP Python knowledge.